# Shutdown threads

Tags: java, tomcat, concurrency

I have a web application deployed on tomcat. In this application are **ExecutorService** to perform some concurrent execution of tasks. There are also few methods within my application which uses Thread native as shown below to perform concurrent executions.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { 
 public void run() {  
   //TODO: Perform some CRUD function 
 }
}).start();
```

When a form POST is invoked against these method the threads are started and perform function execution as desired. My question is, is this a good design approach, or do I have to close the thread after each session, or do I close the threads when tomcat shuts down for say maintenance. Can someone point me on the right direction please.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you do transaction handling?

Comment: Using Hibernate3 Transaction Manager - Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to close the thread after each session, or do I close the threads when tomcat shuts down for say maintenance

I did not quite understand this part, but creating random number of new Threads is a bad idea, firstly it is expensive, secondly it is not possible to create arbitrarily large number of threads, sooner or later you will run into out of memory exceptions. Better work with a thread pool.

Comment: @Bitmap normally you won't want to shutdown pool before your program's exit. Exactly because shutting down/recreating of pool will cause performance penalties and won't give you any benifits in normal circumnstances.

Comment: @Victor Sorokin OIC - so I can assume the pool will be alive till say tomcat shutsdown occationally for maintenance!

Comment: @Bitmap In a normal application function you will not need to explicitly shutdown a threadpool, based on the constructor arguments it will automatically manage the lifecycle of the threads.

Comment: @saugata Ok so Do I need different pool for each class or one parent pool shared by all classes?

Comment: @Bitmap That is a design choice which depends on your requirements, both would be appropriate in different situations.

Comment: @saugata So in terms of Performance and to avoid having to run into out of memory exceptions, which choice do you see fit?

Comment: @Bitmap in the designs I encountered, pool is not shared by several classes. There's single object of single class (typically it's *not* singleton) which handles tasks of one type, e.g., submit of particular form.

Answer (score 0):

Creation and starting of new threads is rather expensive operation. If you concerned about performance, employ `Executors.newCachedThreadPool` method.
Additionally, if you wouldn't need to worry about thread limit exhaustion in case you using some `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`. Note that using this type of executor may cause delays for users should number of users exceed number of threads in pool. However if operation performed by task is short-timed, users hardly notice delay.

Comment: Will Executors.newCachedThreadPool perform the start and close functions for me by default?

Comment: @Bitmap Pool will start threads when they are needed to execute submitted tasks (`Runnable` or `Callable`). Pool won't shutdown threads, because they are reused for new tasks you submit -- that's why it's called pool ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this approach:

1. Creating a new thread is not cheap. Sharing a pool of threads between client connections is a better approach
2. There might be a system imposed limitation on the number of concurrent threads that the JVM can create. Once this limit has reached, new client connections will be rejected.

You can solve these problems by making use of the facilities provided by the `java.util.concurrent` package. See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) for details.

Comment: Alright! so say I was using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7), at what point do you think is Ideal to shutdown the Executor? How do I make a single ExecutorService object available throughout my application classes!